# UPDATE TABLE WITH SELECT AND JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

using Toad / Oracle SQL, I'd appreciate it if anyone could confirm if this is possible, and whether my syntax is correct. Thanks for your help. Gav

```
UPDATE  IYP_MOVE_GS.NET_VALUE_LAST SET  
SELECT IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES.SALES_DOC_NO || IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES.LINE_ITEM AS KEYCODE2
              ,  IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES.NET_VALUE 
            FROM IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES  
            WHERE IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES.LIVE_DATE = '20170131'
JOIN ON      
        IYP_MOVE_GS.KEYCODE = IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES.SALES_DOC_NO || IYP_LIVE_ORDERLINES.LINE_ITEM
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  Oracle does not support `FROM` in a `JOIN`.

Comment: The correct syntax for updating a join is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/8061/update-with-joins#t=201702081750128269372

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use MERGE in this case:

```
merge into iyp_move_gs a
using (
    select 
        sales_doc_no || line_item as keycode,
        net_value 
    from iyp_live_orderlines
    where live_date = '20170131'
) b on (
    a.keycode = b.keycode
) when matched update set a.net_value_last = b.net_value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will give it a go, appreciate your help.